# PowerPoint VBA - Shapes.AddOLEObject - PDF not loading in Web Control?

Tags: vba, pdf, powerpoint, webbrowser-control, powerpoint-2013

I am using the following code to add web browser control to PowerPoint 2013 slide,

```
Set oShp = oSld.Shapes.AddOLEObject(Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=200, Height:=300, Classname:="Shell.Explorer", Link:=msoFalse)
```

The web browser control is set to load a PDF file while in Slide Show mode. But it is not loading the PDF file. Instead I get the following message in the web browser control,

[image]

I understand this has something to do with web browser control security. How to make the PDF file load?

Answer (score 0):

In IE -> Tools -> Internet Otions -> Advanced tab, there is a "Allow active content to run files on My Computer" setting which you can enable. Once enabled, the warning will no longer show up.

If you need to implement this change in multiple computers, you can do this via registry:

To enable Allow active content to run files on My Computer the following registry value must be set to 0:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN
>
> Value Name:  iexplore.exe 
>   Value Type:  REG_DWORD  Value Data:  0

Some helpful reference here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2002093

Comment: Thanks but I tried this and it did not fix the issue.

Comment: The setting required restarting IE, I hope you restarted it?

Comment: I did restart. Same issue.